# Pyside keypress event for textedit

Tags: python, pyside

I have 2 `QTextEdit` widgets and I need to put whatever is entered in the first to the second on a press of the enter key (`Return`).... I am not able to implement it please help?

I know I need to use `KeyPressEvent` but I don't understand how to use it only for the `QTextEdit`??

```
self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.widget)
self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 291))
self.textEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 291))
self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)

self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.widget)
self.textEdit_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 41))
self.textEdit_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(201, 41))
self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
self.textEdit_2.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
```

Any help is appreciated I am stuck.....

Comment: Is this your real problem? It seems kind of redundant to have two `QTextEdit`s containing almost same text.

Comment: i am going to use it as a kind of chat app .... the first one displays entered text....second is used to enter.....

Comment: Now, that makes sense. Why don't use a `QLineEdit` for the input, instead of a `QTextEdit`? It already has a `returnPressed` signal that you can connect to.

Comment: thnx...i will try myself but it would be great if you helped with some code....

Comment: Sure, I've added an answer with a small snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that shows `QLineEdit` and its `returnPressed` signal. Upon pressing return the text in the `QLineEdit` will be appended to the `QTextEdit`:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.output = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)

        self.input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.input.returnPressed.connect(self.addInput)
        self.input.setPlaceholderText('input here')

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)
        layout.addWidget(self.input)

    def addInput(self):
        # skip empty text
        if self.input.text():
            self.output.append(self.input.text())
        # clear the QLineEdit for new input
        self.input.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `viewportEvent` (inherited from `QAbstractScrollArea`)

```
    self.textEdit.viewportEvent.connect(self.copy_the_text)

    def copy_the_text(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, QtGui.QKeyEvent):  # as viewportEvent gets *all* events
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return or event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter:
                # copy the text from textEdit to textEdit_2
```

You can use `Qt.Key_Enter` but I think you probably want `Qt.Key_Return`

#### EDIT

If you are using an older version of `PySide` without new style signals and slots you'll need to use

```
self.connect(self.textEdit, SIGNAL("viewportEvent(event)"), self.copy_the_text)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'connect

Comment: What version of PySide are you using? If it's an older version see edit.

Comment: viewportEvent is a function, not a slot.

Comment: Correct, `viewportEvent` is not a slot